# Using Axios in ReactJS but not able to map array into useState

Tags: reactjs, axios

I'm new to React and facing issues using Axios.
I've created a new create-react-app to isolate the issue I'm facing and upload here for help.
Basic get request using an online api.
The useEffect runs, retrieves the data from the api (you can see the console.log for res.data).
I then setGoal useState with the results, but I can then not read goals in console.log or a .map function.  goals[] array(0)

What am I doing wrong?  Many thanks and happy holidays!

App.js

```
import axios from 'axios'
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
function Goals() {
    const [goals, setGoals] = useState([])
    useEffect(() => {
        const getApi = () => {
            axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/2')
                .then(res => {
                    console.log('res data :', res.data)
                    setGoals(res.data)
                    console.log('goals array :', { goals })
                })
                .catch(err => { console.log(err) })
        }
        getApi()
    }, [])

    return (
        <div>
            {goals ? (
                <><h4>working...</h4>
                    {goals.map((goal) => {
                        <h4>{goal.title}</h4>
                    })}
                </>
            ) : (
                <div><h4>Nothing written</h4></div>
            )
            }
        </div>
    )
}

export default Goals
```

Console log when running:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpWZc.png)

Comment: The `res.data` is an object, not array of objects ...

Comment: If I change the axios.get url (remove the /2), I then get 200+ returned in the res.data in console.log (so array, not object right?) - still the same issue that the goals is 0.

Comment: First of all, from your image, the `data` is an object so it has not `map` method. Then the `console.log` will not work because the `setGoals` is asynchronous, and so the data will be in the `goals` variable in the next render. So, if you fix the object/array problem, the actual code will work. Just the `console.log` is not in the right place.

Answer (score 2):

**first:**
the url that you are using will return a single object ... not an array of objects .. to get the array of objects remove the number at the end of it

```
axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/')
```

**second:** you are not returning anything inside the map function (you forgot to write "return")

```
{goals.map((goal) => {
   return <h4>{goal.title}</h4> 
 })}
```

Comment: Correct on the URL.  I've removed the number and now returning 200 - I was testing and trying to simplify the problem.  Added the return to the map.  But, the useEffect is still not adding the result from the get to the setGoals() and for me to read goals in the map.  I just don't understand why its failing - I watched several videos on Axios and can't see what I'm doing wrong.